# A sticky div displayer issue from css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small website for note-taking purposes, but I encountered an issue. If each container has a lot of content, users can't see the second half of the content in that container. For example, in the first container, they can't see the content 'ZZZ' before scrolling to the next container. Do you have any good solutions?

I tried increasing the height of each container but it still around

```css
body {
  background-color: #808080;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  height: 300vh;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.div-content {
  height: 100%;
}

.first-div {
  top: 0;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.second-div {
  top: 0;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.third-div {
  top: 0;
  border: solid 2px pink;
}

.fourth-div {
  top: 0;
  border: solid 2px purple;
}

.fifth-div {
  top: 0;
  border: solid 2px green;
}

.code {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.note {
  color: purple;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky first-div">
  Container 1: First Div
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>ZZZ</h1>
</div>

<div class="sticky second-div">
  Container 2: Second Div
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
</div>

<div class="sticky third-div">
  Container 3: Third Div
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
</div>

<div class="sticky fourth-div">
  Container 4: fourth Div
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
</div>

<div class="sticky fifth-div">
  Container 5: fifth Div
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
  <h1>XXXX</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey you might get better answers if you post a code snippet that previews your problem within stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @萬次悲傷, Good day You can follow below step to improve the user experience 
- You can stop overleaping container 2 on container 1
- Display content up to certain character only and show a read more / view more link
- On click view more show a modal with overflow y scroll

Hope this can help, If you still need a working example I can post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that none of the cards are actually scrolling, because you've set the div to be sticky it reaches the top of the page and then everything is moving behind it.

The way to prevent this would be to remove the sticky from the divs, and instead sticky the headings.

Here is a minimal recreation

```
<div class="sticky first-div">
    <h2 class="sticky-heading">Container 1: First Div</h2>
    <p>XXXX</p>
</div>
```

```
.sticky {
  height: 300vh;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sticky-heading {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/danhebdon/pen/ExrXLpO) showing the full implementation.